# Using secure websockets (wss) with OkHttp

Tags: android, ssl, websocket, okhttp

I have tried to use `OkHttp3` for connecting to a secure websocket server. When using wss://echo.websocket.org it is working fine, no problem, but when connecting to a production server for an ongoing project I do not properly connect to it. After 30-40 seconds `onClosing` is called in `WebSocketListener`.

I suspect this has something to with SSL/TLS encryption in `wss`. Is there a way to let OkHttpClient accept new certificates?

This is the code I am using now to establish a websocket connection with OkHttp3.

```
WebSocket webSocket;
OkHttpClient client;

OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
client = builder.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(MainActivity.WS_URL)
        .header("Auth-Token","secret-api-token-here")
        .build();
Log.i("WebSockets", "Headers: " + request.headers().toString());
webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {

    private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
        webSocket.send("{Auth-Token:secret-api-token-here}");
        Log.i("WebSockets", "Connection accepted!");
        //webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, "Goodbye !");
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
        Log.i("WebSockets", "Receiving : " + text);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
        Log.i("WebSockets", "Receiving bytes : " + bytes.hex());
    }
    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
        Log.i("WebSockets", "Closing : " + code + " / " + reason);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
        Log.i("WebSockets", "Error : " + t.getMessage());
    }});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `OkHttp3` websocket to connect with a server over encrypted connection `wss` and I face the same problem. Which later turned out that the server was closing the connection after certain period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I wrote the server side as following:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$wsServer = new WsServer(new Chat());

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        $wsServer
    ),
    8080
);

$wsServer->enableKeepAlive($server->loop, 30);

$server->run();
```

Which keep connections alive (enableKeepAlive) using a 30sec ping/pong mechanism.